# Como actualizar correo electronico usando diferentes dominios de email - ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una tabla 'EMPLEADOS' en donde los usuarios tienen una direccion de correo incorrecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo actualizar la dirección de correo utilizando 3 dominios como gmail, yahoo, outlook. tengo una cantidad grande de registros por lo que no puedo hacerlo uno por uno. Estos datos no son reales, por lo que no importa donde se agregue cada dominio.

Cómo puedo escribir esa consulta para actualizarlos de un solo.?

En la columna de email, cada registro debe tener una dirección de correo correcta y Al actualizar los datos, deberia quedar algo como esto:

```
|     EMAIL       |
sking@gmail.com
nkochhar@yahoo.com
ldehaan@outlook.com
name4@yahoo.com
name5@outlook.com
name6@yahoo.com
name7@yahoo.com
name8@outlook.com
name@gmail.com
...
```

Encontré esto en Google pero no se cómo aplicarlo a lo que necesito:

```
for(int i=0; i<rowsCount; i++) {
  cv.put(column2, columnValue[1]);
  cv.put(column3, columnValue[1]);
  db.update(tableName, cv, null, null);
}
```

Intenté hacer esto pero me marca error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Tu interfaz luce como algo relacionado a Oracle, por favor edita y solo deja la etiqueta de la herramienta que estás usando

Comment: Primero, debes saber cuales usuarios pertenecen a cada dominio (que no proveedor). Una vez sepas eso, actualizarlo podría resultar trivial... todo depende de cómo tengas dicha información.

Comment: Cuál es el criterio para dejar outlook, gmail o yahoo, etc? Se asume que esa columna tiene el usuario de cada registro EN el proveedor de correo?

Comment: Estos no son datos reales, por lo que me pidieron agregar uno de los 3 dominios a cada registro que se encuentra en email para formar una dirección de correo electronico correcto.

Comment: Entonces no hay que dar una vuelta tan larga. Corre un count, revisa los employee_id y actualiza guiándote por ese valor

Comment: disculpa cómo sería el codigo de la consulta en sí? no comprendí del todo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que estos no son datos reales, sino de ejemplo, puedes utilizar diversos mecanismos para concatenar un dominio a los distintos correos que ya tienes, por ejemplo, se me ocurre, basándonos en el id, ir asignando los dominios en orden, para que quede así:

```
 id  dominio
==== ==============
  1  @yahoo.com
  2  @gmail.com
  3  @outlook.com
  4  @yahoo.com
  5  @gmail.com
  6  @outlook.com
  y se siga repitiendo el patrón hasta donde sea necesario
```

Esto lo podemos lograr evaluando el residuo de dividir el ID dentro de 3, lo que nos va a devolver siempre un número entre 0 y 2.

```
 id  mod3  dominio
==== ===== ==============
  1     1  @yahoo.com
  2     2  @gmail.com
  3     0  @outlook.com
  4     1  @yahoo.com
  5     2  @gmail.com
  6     0  @outlook.com
  ... etc.
```

En resumen, podemos ligar `0` a `'@outlook.com'`, `1` a `'@yahoo.com'` y `2` a `'@gmail.com'`.

Con esta idea, basados en la función [`mod`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651) podemos armar varias sentencias SQL, donde cada una concatene uno de los dominios a cada correo basándose en el resultado de la operación módulo, por ejemplo, para concatenar `'@outlook.com'`, sería esta:

```sql
update employees
   set email = email || '@outlook.com'
 where mod(employee_id, 3) = 0
   and instr(email, '@') = 0;
```

He agregado la segunda condición para evitar concatenar un dominio a un `email` que ya tiene uno (buscando el símbolo de arroba con la función [`instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651)).

Dejo como ejercicio para el lector escribir las sentencias para concatenar los otros dos dominios.

No está de más decir que se podría escribir una sentencia SQL que actualice todos los registros a la vez. Dada la manera en que se ha formulado la pregunta, considero eso fuera del alcance de la respuesta, pero si es del interés del lector intentarlo, podría basarse en la función [`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)